# Segmentation fault from pointer in fprintf

Tags: c, fortran, fortran77

I am trying to run a program that takes an input file, reads it, and then runs a simulation based on the parameters specified in the input file.  The code is a mixture of C and Fortran77, with the main executable entirely in Fortran77. I did not write the code and I'm inexperienced with both languages (so if I say something stupid, that's why).

Upon running the program, I get the following error regardless of the input file: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

This is the output I get from valgrind, with a few small omissions:

```
Invalid read of size 4
at 0x55ACFDD: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1295)
by 0x55B76B6: fprintf (fprintf.c:32)
by 0x578C64: cfprintf_ (in [path omitted])
by 0x56D288: writebuf_ (writebuf.F:22)
by 0x56D3CC: writemsg_ (writemsg.F:15)
by 0x4C09E7: init0_ (init0.F:68)
by 0x4D6C65: [omitted]
by 0x4E9EC4: main (main.c:113)
Address 0xffffffff0592bbc0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd


Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFFFFFFF0592BBC0
at 0x55ACFDD: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1295)
by 0x55B76B6: fprintf (fprintf.c:32)
by 0x578C64: cfprintf_ (in [path omitted])
by 0x56D288: writebuf_ (writebuf.F:22)
by 0x56D3CC: writemsg_ (writemsg.F:15)
by 0x4C09E7: init0_ (init0.F:68)
by 0x4D6C65: [omitted]
by 0x4E9EC4: main (main.c:113)
If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
possible), you can try to increase the size of the
main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.

HEAP SUMMARY:
 in use at exit: 11,354 bytes in 7 blocks
total heap usage: 46 allocs, 39 frees, 22,590 bytes allocated

LEAK SUMMARY:
definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
possibly lost: 8,008 bytes in 2 blocks
still reachable: 3,346 bytes in 5 blocks
suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory

For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

It seems the `vfprintf.c` and `fprintf.c` files are part of some internal library, because I can't find those files on my computer. `cfprintf.c` is part of my code, shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#ifdef _CRAY
#ifdef FORTRAN_PASSES_ASSUMED_CHAR_LEN 
int CFPRINTF (fileptr, s1, cl1, num_chars)
int *cl1;
#else 
int CFPRINTF (fileptr, s1, num_chars)
#endif 
#else
#ifdef POST_UNDERSCORE
int cfprintf_ (fileptr, s1, num_chars)
#else
int cfprintf (fileptr, s1, num_chars)
#endif
#endif

/* write num_chars characters from string s1 to file associated with fileptr */
FILE **fileptr;
char *s1;
int *num_chars;

{
  char format_string [11];
  char buffer[256];
  sprintf (format_string, "%c.%ds", '%', *num_chars);

  /* write to an intermediate buffer to avoid problems with '\n' */
  sprintf (buffer, format_string, s1);
  fprintf (*fileptr, "%s\n", buffer);
}
```

The line that throws the error is `fprintf (*fileptr, "%s\n", buffer);`
Specifically, I think it's the pointer that is causing the error, but I don't what's wrong or how to fix it.

I had issues compiling the code initially because I am using a 64-bit machine.  The code, which relies heavily on pointers, implicitly declares many if not all of them, so I think that means they take the default 32-bit format of 4-bit integers.  However, on my machine these pointers are 8-bit integers because I compiled in 64 bits.

If `*fileptr` is of one format, but the code is expecting another, perhaps that is what's generating the `Invalid read of size 4` message from valgrind?  But like I said, if that's the problem I still don't know how to fix it.

Thanks for your help, and please let me know if there's any additional code I should post.

Comment: Why are you using K&R style parameter declarations instead of prototypes? The 1970's called, they want their C back.

Comment: And make sure your `format_string` buffer has enough room for the `sprintf` output. It is also a **VERY BAD IDEA** to pass the `printf`-like functions a `format` string constructed at run-time.

Comment: Looks like you are passing a 32 bit pointer `0xFFFFFFFF0592BBC0` to a function expecting 64 bits.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: that is technically a 64-bit pointer, though the high 32-bit are all set (which is admittedly suspicious, though it may be a Valgrind thing).

Comment: Show how you are calling this function when the error occurs. Also, are you allowed to change this function, and what is your compiler and version?

Comment: Does the Fortran code call any C functions directly?

Comment: We need more code.  Can you post your main.c?

Comment: @Barmar Considering it is combined with **Fortran 77**, that's average. Such pre-processor macros are pretty standard in many long lived libraries that are originally written pre-ANSI C (C89/90), and on code ported to numerous Unix workstations. So it probably was originally written some point _before_ 1990.

Comment: Well `vfprintf` and `fprintf` are standard C library functions (declared in stdarg.h and stdio.h respectively). Available on most Unix and Unix-like systems. So unless you have the debugging symboles for the standard C library installed, that would be normal.

Comment: You may try a compiler option which promotes all Fortran integers to 64 bits, most compilers I know have it, although with different names (you did not indicate your compiler).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you definitely shouldn't be constructing your format string at runtime like that. Use the following instead:

```
snprintf(buffer, 256, "%.*s", *num_chars, s1);
```

or even just

```
fprintf(*fileptr, "%.*s\n", *num_chars, s1);
```

`.*` allows the width of the string to be dynamically specified.

Next, I would check that your `fileptr` is valid, and that it was successfully opened. The address `0xffffffff0592bbc0` is very suspicious due to the four high bytes all being `0xff`, so it is possible that you are having 32-bit/64-bit issues.

Comment: Suggest `snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer,...` rather than `256`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question, the application has been known to work in the past, but compiled on 32-bit Unix systems? (That's the only environment I've seen old Fortran and C code mixed in a single program *in general*.)

Unless you want to [port the application to 64-bit](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-port64/) I would suggest you simply compile it as an 32-bit native application, assuming your operating system allows 32-bit applications to run in a 64-bit environment.

For example using the `gcc` compiler the flag `-m32` is all you need to add for 64-bit x86 processor systems. I believe `clang` supports the same flag, but if not check the documentation.

A second potential complicating factor, is whether the program / application (or its data) is [endian dependent](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html), which may be an issue if was written under the assumption of being run on BIG ENDIAN CPUs, such as the majority of Unix workstations with RISC-style processors (MIPS, PowerPC, etc.), and you are now trying to run it on an 64-bit x86 Intel or AMD processor (aka amd64, x86-64).

My advice in this case is to <s>hurt someone</s>..., er, review the important of the application and its usage.